# webpack-runtime js files getting a 404

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I've got a site built on Gatsby/Netlify that just recently started having an intermittent issue where some of the js assets return a 404. The issue seems to appear and go away on its own. Here's a screenshot of the devtools console:
[image]

What kinds of things should I check?

Comment: Having the same issue, resolved itself in 5min or so, but very concerning :/

Comment: @usagidon are you using Netlify also?

Comment: No, our gatsby site is served from S3, so opening an issue in the Gatsby repo wouldn't be a bad idea

Comment: Update on this, it maybe Netlify-related after all. We are using a passthrough proxy redirect in Netlify's TOML file for some of our old pages still being hosted on our previous architecture/server. There seems to be some linkage between Netlify's caching and the Varnish cache on our old server.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have `gatsby-plugin-offline` installed and it is caching old files.

The Gatsby community is still [looking for ways](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11240) to 100% solve this issue, but there is a temporary solution that other websites have been using if being a PWA is not incredibly important to your use-case:

1. Remove `gatsby-plugin-offline` from `gatsby-config.js`.
2. Add `gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker` to `gatsby-config.js`.
3. `$ yarn add gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker`

This will:

1. Prevent your website from creating service-workers on new visitors.
2. Remove service-workers and effectively removing the caching capability from returning visitors.

Comment: We used to have that installed! But we had issues and used `gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker` as you describe. However now that I'm looking, I see `gatsby-plugin-offline` is still in our package.json file.... but that shouldn't affect anything if it's not in our `gatsby-config.js` right?

Comment: I see, you are correct -- `gatsby-plugin-offline` should not affect the app if it's not in `gatsby-config.js`.

How are you uploading these files to S3? Are you using `aws s3 sync` or `gatsby-plugin-s3`?

Comment: No we're not using either of those.

Comment: There might be an instance of time where your new HTML files are uploaded, but they point to dependencies (e.g. webpack-runtime-[chunk].js) which are still in the upload queue. 

Many scripts that push to S3 upload the files in alphabetical order. This means 'index.html' will be uploaded at the beginning and it's dependencies like webpack-runtime-[chunk].js will be uploaded much later (sometimes even minutes!) thus 404'ing.

Looking at the filenames & that it's intermittent & fixes itself, this might be the issue. If so, try changing the deployment script to uploading HTML files last.